# Which site should I use for demographics questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Specifically, I want to ask about the difference between income per capita and GDP per capita, because I've looked at those statistics for the same area and they don't seem to be the same. Also, I want to know if there is a database for GDP of US counties and where to find it. So which SE site should I use to ask these types of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general question about about definitions and concepts, ask [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

To ask where to obtain the data, you could ask [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).